# How to populate database with generated data in visual studio 2010 / SSMS 2008?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, data-generation

In my (c#) Visual Studio 2010 project i have a reference to a database.

However, the database is empty. I would like to insert some bogus data in this database so that i can test my app.

Are there any tools / methods for doing so?

Thanks!

Comment: What flavour of VS2010 do you have?

Comment: so i from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833237(v=vs.100).aspx that it is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using sql I would recommend [redgate's sql data generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/) it isn't free but does a very good job of creating useful test data

Comment: if you only need to do it once, then you can take advantage of their 30 day frree trial.

Comment: great, does indeed exactly what i want. i'll opt for a lincense with the management.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created or create a database project in VS2010 there are tools built in to generate data:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833267(v=vs.100).aspx

It says you need Visual Studio Premium but I am using VS2010 Profesional and I can do it.